# How to make three grouped rectangles?

Tags: html, border

I would like to make three grouped rectangles with text content and rounded corners, but I don't know quite how to?

Any code snippets would be appreciated.

```html
<style> * { font-family: "arial" }</style> 
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
}
</style>
<h1 class="small" style="background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-size: auto; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: inherit; font-size: 22px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; orphans: 2; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 15px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">-</h1><span style="display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">
</span><div class="field" style="background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-size: auto; border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-image-outset: 0; border-image-repeat: stretch; border-image-slice: 100%; border-image-source: none; border-image-width: 1; border-left-color: rgb(225, 225, 225); border-left-style: solid; border-left-width: 1px; border-right-color: rgb(225, 225, 255); border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: 1px; border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px; orphans: 2; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">(-) <br></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;

}


.box1{
  padding:10px;
  background: red;
  color:white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size:18px;
 }
.box2 {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
 padding:10px;
}
 .box3 {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
  <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
<div class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `border-radius` to class **.field** as shown below

```
.field{border-radius: 10px;}
```

Here is the fiddle:

```html
<style>
  * {
    font-family: "arial"
  }
.field{border-radius: 10px;}
</style>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
</style>
<h1 class="small" style="background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-size: auto; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: inherit; font-size: 22px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; orphans: 2; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 15px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">-</h1><span style="display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">
</span>
<div class="field" style=" background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-size: auto; border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-image-outset: 0; border-image-repeat: stretch; border-image-slice: 100%; border-image-source: none; border-image-width: 1; border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-left-style: solid; border-left-width: 1px; border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: 1px; border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px; orphans: 2; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">(-) <br></div>
```

**Note:** Please avoid inline styling and try to use css shorthand properties for example `padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;` for good coding practice.

Clean version:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

* {
  font-family: "arial"
}

.field {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.small {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
}

.abc {
  display: inline !important;
  float: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
}

.field {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="small">-</h1><span class="abc">
</span>
<div class="field">(-) <br></div>
```

Comment: you can do that add parent class to your html and also dont use inline style write this in css file

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style> * { font-family: "arial" }</style> 
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
}
.field {
  border: 2px solid red !important;
  border-radius:5px;
}
</style>
<h1 class="small" style="background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-size: auto; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: inherit; font-size: 22px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; orphans: 2; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 15px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">-</h1><span style="display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">
</span><div class="field" style="background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-size: auto; border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-image-outset: 0; border-image-repeat: stretch; border-image-slice: 100%; border-image-source: none; border-image-width: 1; border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-left-style: solid; border-left-width: 1px; border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: 1px; border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px; orphans: 2; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">(-) <br></div>
```